# Images/Sprites question in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, image-scaling, ccsprite

Okay, so I have a background image of a desert for my app, it is in the .gif format, and is @2x. I have it scaled down like so:

```
background.scale = 0.5;
```

and it appears fine. I have another image for a health bar that is in .png format, and is also @2x. I also have it scaled down like above. But the health bar is WAY pixelated on the edges, and the desert's edges are not AS pixelated, but WAY better. I've tried changing the health bar's format to .gif, that didn't do anything. And note: When I view the images in Preview/Xcode, they look just fine! Am I missing something? I use Inkscape, if that helps. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you scaling a health bar?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, scaling in cocos2d is not recommended as it is low quality (as you observe) and it becomes a performance bottleneck (or it used to be, I don't know this could have changed). Why don't you just pre-scale the images to the exact dimensions you want and display them without scaling? If this is for a universal app, just pre-scale the images to each intended resolution and load them depending on the screen scale/size.

Comment: I'd planned on doing that, but then I remembered, why is the desert background not pixelated, even though it's scaled?

Comment: What if you need to scale images at run time?